# Xamarin forms shell pages hierarchy

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, I need to add navigation as follows:
1.MainPage (its need to have hamburger menu, but itself it isnt present in the hamburger menu)

Pages that are in the hamburger menu it will  be presented as a children of the root page (each page will be having back arrow pointed to MainPage)

a. Page1
b. Page2
.
.
.
xy. Page(n)

Should I add ShellItem and inside of a shellItem add FlyoutItem?

Comment: If you use shell,MainPage will be the rootpage (as a MasterDetailPage).

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT can you post an answer with appshell.xaml code?

Comment: Have take a look at [xaminals sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) or [examples from documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout)